# Como Aninhar um terceiro nested_form no rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho os seguintes models:
`Prova`, 
`Questao`, 
`Alternativa`.

Estando os mesmos com as seguintes associações:

```
Prova has_many :questoes

Questao belongs_to :prova

Questao has_many :alternativas

Alternativa belongs_to :questao
```

Estou usando a `gem nested_form` para fazer o formulário aninhado, só que não estou conseguindo fazer o nested_form de alternativas, tendo em vista que não tenho o `Controller` de questão (pois eles serão apenas atributos dentro do controller de prova), como eu faria esse aninhamento?

Answer (score 0):

Está faltando uma linha no seu models/questao.rb

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :alternativas
```

Comment: Estava faltando um pouco mais que isso, mas deu pra resolver, obrigado!